# mysql transaction returning empty result set

Tags: mysql, transactions

I'm new to mysql and currently trying to learn about transactions. One of my practice problems deals with a table called accounts, which stores the account number, customer ID, and balance of different bank accounts. Running the query

```
SELECT SUM(balance) FROM accounts
```

yields the correct result:

```
-----------
| balance |
-----------
|  1000   |
-----------
```

But when I put this in a transaction, like:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT SUM(balance) as total_balance FROM account;
COMMIT;
```

suddenly nothing is returned. What's going on here?

Comment: You don't need a transaction there. You'll need one when you have multiple SQL statements you want to be committed as a whole.

Comment: @TheImpaler I kind of had a hunch this was the case, as I remember reading that single statements are automatically transactions. So I tried displaying the balances of a couple accounts separately, like BEGIN; SELECT account_num, balance FROM account WHERE account_num = '1'; SELECT account_num, balance FROM account WHERE account_num = '2'; COMMIT; Here, i was expecting two rows to be displayed. Yet I got 0, again.

Comment: Even though a transaction is useless in the example you posted, it still shows the value you want. The tool you are using, however, may not receive it or display it appropriately. What tool are you using? Remember, those are three separate instructions; run them one by one, and the second one will show the result you want.

Comment: @TheImpaler i tried simply using my terminal instead of the interactive UI, and the select statement worked. Thanks